# How to fix the grpc error "Failed to dial target "?

Tags: grpc, grpcurl

when i executed command line as follow:

```
grpcurl -plaintext -d "{\"job_id\": \"test\",\"batch_id\": 1}" 10.80.31.108:8083 datacenter.DatacenterService/ListStripInfo
```

error reported:

```
Failed to dial target host "10.80.31.108:8083": dial tcp 10.80.31.108:8083: connectex: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
```

what may cause this error?

Answer (score 0):

The important part of the error message is `connectex: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions`. This indicates that the connection was rejected by a firewall.

[ConnectEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mswsock/nc-mswsock-lpfn_connectex) is a Windows API for working with sockets. Looking at the [list of the socket errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2), it appears that you got have `10013 WSAEACCES`:

> Permission denied.
> An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. An example is using a broadcast address for sendto without broadcast permission being set using setsockopt(SO_BROADCAST).
> Another possible reason for the WSAEACCES error is that when the bind function is called (on Windows NT 4.0 with SP4 and later), another application, service, or kernel mode driver is bound to the same address with exclusive access. Such exclusive access is a new feature of Windows NT 4.0 with SP4 and later, and is implemented by using the SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE option.